# How do I make double-line horizontal table borders in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I want to get a double-lined horizontal border for my table in Docs, like Word has. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is currently not an option (as of May 4th, 2020), I found an ingenious hack to do it, and I created a webapps SE account just to share this.

First make a table. Then duplicate it below, so that both tables are aligned. It should look like this:

[image]

Then click on that empty line between the two tables, and click `line spacing` in the main toolbar:

[image]

Select `Custom Spacing` and you'll get a popup. Change the `Line spacing` attribute to 0.06 (the minimum allowed currently) and the `Before` and `After` paragraph spacings to 0, and click `Apply`.

[image]

And you'll get a beautifully double-lined horizontal border for your table! :)

[image]